# Map Keys to send events and use them

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, alienware

I have an Alienware 15r3 and it has some extra AlienFx Keys, which have the following behaviour on windows. There are 6 Keys

1. Lets call the first key the mode switch key. It changes the mode for the remaining keys. In total there are 3 modes.
2. The remaining keys can be configured to be used to do anything using the AlienFX software on windows.

I checked for life in those keys using

`xev | sed -n 's/^.*state \([0-9].*\), keycode *\([0-9]\+\) *\(.*\), .*$/keycode \2 = \3, state = \1/p'`

which launched an event tester window, but this could not catch it, so I installed `evtest` which could catch it

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event3:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event5:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event6:  SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
/dev/input/event7:  Intel HID events
/dev/input/event8:  Integrated_Webcam_HD
/dev/input/event9:  Dell WMI hotkeys
/dev/input/event10: HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event11: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event12: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event13: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event14: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event15: SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse
Select the device event number [0-15]: 3
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x11 vendor 0x1 product 0x1 version 0xab41
Input device name: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 32 (KEY_D)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 89 (KEY_RO)
    Event code 90 (KEY_KATAKANA)
    Event code 91 (KEY_HIRAGANA)
    Event code 92 (KEY_HENKAN)
    Event code 93 (KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA)
    Event code 94 (KEY_MUHENKAN)
    Event code 95 (KEY_KPJPCOMMA)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 112 (KEY_MACRO)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 117 (KEY_KPEQUAL)
    Event code 118 (KEY_KPPLUSMINUS)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 121 (KEY_KPCOMMA)
    Event code 122 (KEY_HANGUEL)
    Event code 123 (KEY_HANJA)
    Event code 124 (KEY_YEN)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 143 (KEY_WAKEUP)
    Event code 148 (KEY_PROG1)
    Event code 149 (KEY_PROG2)
    Event code 155 (KEY_MAIL)
    Event code 156 (KEY_BOOKMARKS)
    Event code 157 (KEY_COMPUTER)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 159 (KEY_FORWARD)
    Event code 161 (KEY_EJECTCD)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 172 (KEY_HOMEPAGE)
    Event code 173 (KEY_REFRESH)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 217 (KEY_SEARCH)
    Event code 226 (KEY_MEDIA)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML) state 0
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL) state 0
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL) state 0
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1490889095.961909, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1c
Event: time 1490889095.961909, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 28 (KEY_ENTER), value 0
Event: time 1490889095.961909, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889110.696159, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 91
Event: time 1490889110.696159, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889110.706599, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 91
Event: time 1490889110.706599, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889110.819088, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 92
Event: time 1490889110.819088, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889110.829437, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 92
Event: time 1490889110.829437, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889110.931606, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 93
Event: time 1490889110.931606, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889110.940715, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 93
Event: time 1490889110.940715, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889111.023392, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 94
Event: time 1490889111.023392, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889111.032459, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 94
Event: time 1490889111.032459, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889111.130782, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 95
Event: time 1490889111.130782, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889111.138889, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 95
Event: time 1490889111.138889, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889111.276061, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 96
Event: time 1490889111.276061, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1490889111.285473, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 96
Event: time 1490889111.285473, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Please Notice the events after `Testing ... (interrupt to exit`, these belong to the keys that I call the extra AlienFX keys. I want to know if there is something wrong with this. And if there is how do I fix it and map them, and if there is not than the same. Map them

Comment: P.S. help me with formatting, please couldn't figure out how to give a scrollbar

Comment: haha found it now